Displaying all Results for Prime Numbers on One Popup Window
I am trying to create a password generator in Python. I'm starting off by writing a program to generate prime numbers to use when calculating RSA, and I found a program that I modified to display results through popups via PySimpleGUI. However, I'm having trouble getting all my results on one popup window.
Here's my code so far:
import PySimpleGUI as sg

start = int(sg.popup_get_text("Enter the start of the range: " ))
end = int(sg.popup_get_text("Enter the end of the range: "))

for num in range(start, end + 1):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, int(num**0.5) + 1):
            if(num % i) == 0:
                break
        
        else:
            sg.popup(num)

sg.popup("The process is complete. Press OK to close.")

How can I get all the results to be displayed on one popup window?

You are making a popup for every prime number. Instead, make a list and append all prime numbers to the list, and then display the list in one popup.
import PySimpleGUI as sg

start = int(sg.popup_get_text("Enter the start of the range: " ))
end = int(sg.popup_get_text("Enter the end of the range: "))

nums = []

for num in range(start, end, 1):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, int(num**0.5) + 1):
            if (num % i == 0):
                break
            else:
                nums.append(num)
sg.popup(nums)
sg.popup("The process is complete. Press OK to close.")


Bad indent for the statements else: nums.append(num).

You can join all prime numbers by using the method str.join, then pass it as the arguments of the sg.popup, like
import PySimpleGUI as sg

nums = [f"{i}" for i in range(100)]
message = ", ".join(nums)
sg.popup(message, title="Prime Number")


It may work bad if message is too long to fit on your screen.
You can use some elements with scrollbar to show more, like sg.Multiline.
Programming for GUI, not work it like as in the console, but handling all user events on graphic interface.
Example Code
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))
layout_left = [
    [sg.Multiline("", disabled=True, size=(40, 10), pad=(0, 0), expand_x=True, key="RESULT")],
]
layout_right = [
    [sg.VPush()],
    [sg.Text("Fm"), sg.Input(size=10, key="FM", focus=True)],
    [sg.Text("To"), sg.Input(size=10, key='TO')],
    [sg.Text("", expand_x=True, justification='center', key="MESSAGE")],
    [sg.VPush()],
    [sg.Button("Search", expand_x=True)],
]
layout = [[sg.Column(layout_left), sg.Column(layout_right, expand_y=True)]]
window = sg.Window("Prime Number", layout, margins=(0, 0))

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "Exit"):
        break

    elif event == "Search":
        window["MESSAGE"].update("")
        try:
            start, stop = int(values["FM"]), int(values["TO"])
        except ValueError:
            window["MESSAGE"].update("<Bad Number>")
            continue
        primes = []
        for num in range(start, stop + 1):
            if num > 1:
                for i in range(2, int(num**0.5) + 1):
                    if(num % i) == 0:
                        break
                else:
                    primes.append(str(num))
        window["RESULT"].update(", ".join(primes))

window.close()


Note: More content for element sg.Multiline may slow down the response time of your GUI.

You should store your numbers in 1 variable. For example you can use list:
result = []

for num in range(start, end + 1):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, int(num**0.5) + 1):
            if(num % i) == 0:
                break
        
        else:
            result.append(num)

sg.popup(f'Numbers are: {result}')


Your code as-is creates a popup once per iteration of the for loop. That's why it creates a new popup for every number; every time it reaches the next prime, it has to start a new pop-up from scratch.
If you want all the numbers to appear in one pop-up, you have to call sg.popup precisely one time after all your looping is done. That necessitates storing your primes in some way or another while you do the calculations; a list is probably the best choice.
Your existing code with a few minor modifications will get the job done:
import PySimpleGUI as sg

start = int(sg.popup_get_text("Enter the start of the range: " ))
end = int(sg.popup_get_text("Enter the end of the range: "))

primes = [] # Intialize an empty list; we'll fill this with primes later
for num in range(start, end + 1):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, int(num**0.5) + 1):
            if(num % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(str(num)) # Instead of creating a popup immediately, add it to the list

sg.popup(" ".join(primes)) # Now join all the primes with spaces and create one combined popup

sg.popup("The process is complete. Press OK to close.")

